# Volley passing a JsonArray Request to Arraylist

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Hi am new to android am trying to pass a json response to arraylist using jsonarray request but i am getting this error :

Error:

volley error org.json.JSONException: Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Php code:

```
$userid=$_POST["userid"];

$semester=$_POST["semester"];

$level=$_POST["level"];

$stmt="SELECT coursecode,coursetitle,grade,credithrs,marks FROM tblresults WHERE userid = '$userid' and semester = '$semester' and level = '$level'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$stmt);
$responsea=array();

while($respons=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $response["coursecode"]=$respons['coursecode'];
    $response["coursetitle"]=$respons['coursetitle'];
    $response["grade"]=$respons['grade'];
    $response["credithrs"]=$respons['credithrs'];
    $response["marks"]=$respons['marks'];
    $responsea[]=$response;
    }   
echo json_encode($responsea);
```

Php response:

```
[{"coursecode":"csc234","coursetitle":"Information Security","grade":"A","credithrs":"3","marks":"80.00"},{"coursecode":"csc300","coursetitle":"Cryptography","grade":"B","credithrs":"3","marks":"65.00"}]
```

android code:

```
    public ArrayList<resultInstance> extractresult() {

    CheckResultFragment checkResultFragment=new CheckResultFragment();
    final String gsem=checkResultFragment.gsem;
    final String glev=checkResultFragment.glev;

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, jsonurl, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    int i=0;
                    while (i<response.length()){
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                            resultInstance resultinstance =new resultInstance(
                                    jsonObject.getString("coursecode"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("coursetitle"),
                                    jsonObject.getInt("credit"),
                                    jsonObject.getDouble("marks"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("grade"));
                            results.add(resultinstance);
                            i++;
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("userid",guid);
            params.put("level",glev);
            params.put("semester",gsem);

            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);

    return  results;
}
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Do debug and set breakpoints, your API call php response is not in a format of JSONArray. Send proper JSONArray format as a response to the API call request.

Comment: hi can you please give me an example of a proper JSONArray format.

Comment: `[{"coursecode":"csc234","coursetitle":"Information Security","grade":"A","credithrs":"3","marks":"80.00"},{"coursecode":"csc300","coursetitle":"Cryptography","grade":"B","credithrs":"3","marks":"65.00"}]`

Your JSONArray format is correct. But sometimes, using PHP backend, HTML tags also comes along with response. E.g. `< br` . In that case, the above exception occurs.

Comment: So is there anyway to combat this error because i have being researching but haven't any solutions yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to fix this error in PHP backend code. Specifically on the sending response code segment.